# react-native-elements Overlay border transparency

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I'm trying to make a transparent overlay container but although I've set `overlayBackgroundColor` to transparent, there still exists the ugly shadow border over it.

I've tried:

```js
<Overlay
  overlayStyle={{opacity: 1, shadowOpacity: 0}}
  overlayBackgroundColor={Colors.transparent}
  borderRadius={0}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the following prop to the overlay.

```
fullScreen={true}
```

Like this:

```
 <Overlay
    fullScreen={true}
    overlayBackgroundColor="transparent">
</Overlay>
```

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Overlay` is made fullscreen, then one loses the event `onBackdropPress` that may be leveraged to close the `Overlay`. To remove the shadow and still get to trigger the event `onBackdropPress`, disable shadow effects through `overlayStyle`.

```
<Overlay
    onBackdropPress={() => console.log('Backdrop pressed')}
    windowBackgroundColor='rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)'
    overlayBackgroundColor='transparent'
    width='auto'
    height='auto'
    overlayStyle={{ elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0 }}>
</Overlay>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that some of the properties, which are suggested by other answers, like windowBackgroundColor, are no longer supported!

The following worked for me.

```js
<Overlay
    overlayStyle={{ backgroundColor: "transparent", elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0 }}
>
...
</Overlay>
```